# How to generate release version numbers without relying on a CI build number?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, versioning, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

My current CD pipeline for my webapp has three steps

- backend, builds Spring Boot backend with gradle
- frontend, build angular frontend with ng, runs in parallel with backend step
- containerize, create a container image and publish to docker hub, runs via a manual trigger after backend and frontend are successful. The published image has multiple tags one of them is a build number tag with format `build-num` so something like `build-123` or `build-525`. The build number comes from bitbucket pipelines build number environment variable.
- backend and front end in same git repo

I want to replace the build number that is generated with bitbucket pipeline with a version number that is not derived from the CI system but is more intrinsic to the git repo itself and enables the workflow of publishing some commits as container images but not all commits.

Questions:

- What techniques can be used to derive a human friendly version number that is not just git the hash. The version number must be sortable I want to able to look at two version numbers and determine the order they were released in.

Answer (score 1):

We have an Open Source tool for that: https://github.com/relizaio/versioning

We also have SaaS solution for more advanced cases (Reliza Hub - in Public Preview mode until the end of 2021). See my article here describing the options and usage for both: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/

Note though that it is a common practice to build docker containers on every git push. If CI tests pass, there is not much reason to skip building containers as there are various ways to later delete older images automatically on the image registry side.